# how to get image caption using php

Tags: php, image, get, title, caption

I'm using PHP to put all the images in a given folder into a slideshow.
This works fine in the following code:

```
<?php
//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = array();
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

/****** Display Images ******/
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    //I would like to get the image title here, to put in the echo below    
    echo "<div><img src='$img' border='0' width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/ /></div>"; 
    }
?>
```

This all goes quite easy, but since I would now also like to add the Titles of the pictures as captions, I need to extract/get this information from the image.

I'm thinking I can get it with something along the lines of the function `exif_read_data` , but I'm not quite sure how to get the title and not all the meta data . . .

---

With a little help from the smart people using stackoverflow, this is the final and functional result, as seen in my answer below as well and again, made with bits and pieces from several answers.

```
<?php
/*
This script will print the image files in a given folder, along with their image description (title in windows file explorer).
*/

// Set the directory where the files reside
$directory = $GLOBALS['directory'];

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$imagenpath = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = array();
// create array
foreach($imagenpath as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

// Print each image file with the ImageDescription (the title/caption) in the ALT field
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $exif_data = exif_read_data($img, 'IFD0');
    $exif_description = "";
    if (!empty($exif_data['ImageDescription'])) 
        $exif_description = $exif_data['ImageDescription'];

    echo "<div><img src='$img' alt='$exif_description' border='0' width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/ /></div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the image title located? Also `foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }` seems unnecessary.

Comment: The results returned from `exif_read_data` are returned, from memory, in a multidimensional array and the details within the exif data depends entirely upon what created them in the first place and whether or not they have been edited / manipulated at all. You would need to parse the array that gets returned and cherrypick the bits you want / need

Comment: The image title is located in the file :)
I can set the title (comment and other stuff) by simply editing the jpg file in windows, but I'm not sure if that's what you meant.  The code bits like `foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }` wouldn't be necessary with using the glob() function directly?
I got the code, rather than writing myself - didn't really do much PHP and not since 10 years.

I figure the title data must be in this multidimensional array somewhere, but I'm at a loss to find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats everything that can be done, because most pictures are not supported with this function, though, you are doing it wrong because the error that you are getting is because the file is not found, the error you get when the file is found and is not supported is this:

> Warning: exif_read_data(file.png): File not supported in
>   /path/to/file/file.php on line x

and its because you single quoted the variable in

```
    $exif_data = exif_read_data($img, 'IFD0');
```

the code could be less characters, this is my solution:

```
<?php
/*
This script will print the image files in a given folder, along with their image description (title in windows file explorer).
*/

// Set the directory where the files reside
$directory = $GLOBALS['directory'];

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$imgs = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

// Print each image file with the ImageDescription (the title/caption) in the ALT field
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $exif_data = exif_read_data($img, 'IFD0');
    if (!empty($exif_data['ImageDescription'])) 
        $exif_description = $exif_data['ImageDescription'];

    echo "<div><img src=\"$img\" alt=\"$exif_description\" border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/ /></div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanx mate - I overlooked that one!

Comment: That was basically the last part of the puzzle, with the other info above it now works!

Comment: you're welcome :), please mark it as the answer so it won't appear in the unanswered section

Comment: Well it's just that it's only a part of the answer - I posted the full code answer below, but I'd be happy to credit you instead, if you make a full code answer that people can use.
So I'll wait a bit with marking it the answer...

Comment: i guess the solution is better now. less code, same functionality = faster (in a few msecs though)

Comment: Yeps - looks good and I should actually cut my code down a bit as well :)

Thanks for participating :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $name = basename($filename, '.jpg');
    echo "<div><img src='$filename' title='$name' alt='$name' border='0' width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/ /></div>";
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error on the first line . . .
Wouldn't this code get something else than the Image title?

Comment: Its working fine at my side. In glob function put the path of your all images. exp:- images/*.jpg

Comment: When I remove the `;` trailing the glob function the thing works, except that it doesn't print the title, but rather just the file name, e.g.
`<img src="photos/test/testpic00.jpg" title="testpic00" alt="testpic00" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">`

The title for this particular picture is actually **Title 1**

BTW thanx for trying :)

Comment: you are correct @jimmi lee - there should not be a semi-colon after the glob function call. This will not return the image titles that you seek - it is however a quick method to retrieve the various images in your directory. To get the exif data I suggest you try with just one image using `exif_read_data` ~ sort of like: `print_r( exif_read_data( realpath( 'c:/temp/images/image1.jpg' ) ) );` to see the structure of the array - then you can target the necessary elements in your loop once you know the location in the array

Comment: @RamRaider You're right and I did see examples of code doing just that by other people.  However, as the structure of the exif_data differs rather widely, I'm worried that it will throw errors in many cases.  
I'll probably look into the above a bit more and see if I can't catch something, once I'm done with a few other things today.

Comment: @RamRaider I gave your idea a short try, first with one picture that gave some more or less intelligible answer, but the second file gave a rather different answer... However, when looking at the long string of confusing elements that it spits out, I can actually find the captions I put in to each picture and at least they are in the same "part" - like this:
`[ImageDescription] => Caption 1` 
So then the question becomes how to extract the ImageDescription and not title or comment.  Of course I don't personally care what it's called, as long as it can hold a caption of sorts  :)

Comment: Trying this one gives me an error on the prin_r line...
`foreach ($imgs as $img) {
 print_r( exif_read_data($img));
}`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I basically used the Windows file browser, selected the image file and entered the text in the document comments section.

Then I printed the `$exif_data` as suggested above by @RamRaider and found out this text ends up in the `ImageDescription` of the file.

Once I nailed down the errors in my script, along with help from @Abdallah Samman, there wasn't much to it anymore!

Thank you everyone...

The following works beautifully:

```
<?php
/*
This script will print the image files in a given folder, along with their image description.
*/

// Set the directory where the files reside
$directory = $GLOBALS['directory'];

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$imagenpath = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = array();
// create array
foreach($imagenpath as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }

// Print each image file with the ImageDescription (the caption) in the ALT field
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $exif_data = exif_read_data($img, 'IFD0');
    $exif_description = "";
    if (!empty($exif_data['ImageDescription'])) 
        $exif_description = $exif_data['ImageDescription'];

    echo "<div><img src='$img' alt='$exif_description' border='0' width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"/ /></div>";
}
?>
```